# Best way to test Get() method of controller

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, nunit

I have the following constructor with a get () method and I need to test if this method works correctly through NUnit.

```
public ConsumersController(IProvider<Consumer> provider)
{
  this.provider = provider;
}

/// <summary>
/// Get the list of consumers that you are allowed to see and serve
/// </summary>
/// <response code="200">Returns the consumers you are allowed to see and serve</response>
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<Consumer>), 200)]
[Produces(typeof(IEnumerable<Consumer>))]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(IEnumerable<Consumer>))]
public IEnumerable<Consumer> Get()
{
  return this.provider.GetAll();
}
```

I created this code based on this link [Testing controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing) but I do not know if it is correct, the test does not pass.
Thanks in advance.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ConsumerTest
{
    private readonly HttpClient consumerHttp;

    private readonly ConsumersController consumerControl;

    [Test]
    public async Task Get_ConsumersController()
    {
        var result = this.consumerControl.Get();
        var response = await consumerHttp.GetAsync("http://localhost:9000/consumers");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var consumerList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Consumer>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
        var consumerTest = consumerList.First();

        Assert.AreEqual(result.First().Name, consumerTest.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on _test does not pass_? Do you get different names? Any names at all? I'm not an expert on controller action tests, but I'm not sure if this is really unit test material. As long as the controller action doesn't do anything but returning a list of objects I'd rather test the `IProvider` implementation you're using.

Comment: I see two problems with the code that you posted. First, your `Get` method in your `ConsumersController` is not an `async` method. Your unit test method for it is treating it as if it was defined as `async`. Second issue is I don't see an `IProvider<Consumer>` mock or object being created for your controller.

Comment: The linked article covers both unit and integration testing. Can you clarify exactly which one you are referring to as currently the question is too broad for us to be able to provide any meaningful help to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers. In fact it lacked to use the MOQ library and there was an error with the use of Async. I got it with this code.

```
[Test]
public void Get_ReturnsAConsumer_WithAListOfIProvider()
{
  var mockRepo = new Mock<IProvider<Consumer>>();
  mockRepo.Setup(repo => repo.GetAll()).Returns(GetConsumers());

  var controller = new ConsumersController(mockRepo.Object);
  var result = controller.Get();

  Assert.IsAssignableFrom<List<Consumer>>(result);
  Assert.AreEqual(1, result.Count());
}
```

Comment: In my project, I do both unit tests (how controller interacts with its dependencies, what status codes in different scenarios) using Moq and functional tests using HttpClient